# How to fetch all revisions in SVN given an arbitrary path and revision number?

Tags: svn

Say that you have a the following history:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | developer | 2014-04-14 19:37:18 -0700 (Mon, 14 Apr 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /def.txt
   A /ghi.txt (from /def.txt:2)

blah
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | developer | 2014-04-14 19:37:01 -0700 (Mon, 14 Apr 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /abc.txt
   A /def.txt (from /abc.txt:1)

renamed file
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | developer | 2014-04-14 19:36:42 -0700 (Mon, 14 Apr 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /abc.txt
```

If you only know about abc.txt@1, how can you get the entire history including r2 and r3?

Comment: If you can obtain this log, you can fetch the revisions it describes, no? I don't understand your constraint. How could you only know about one commit if you have SVN access?

Comment: I am working with another tool that has paths and revisions numbers stored in isolation from the history.  That tool only knows about r1.  If I go to SVN directly and view a log from the command line, I can discern the history of that file, but how would I do that programmatically?  It's not so simple when you've got file renames and deletes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't track history of renames in reverse order. Period

Comment: Why is that?  A limitation of SVN's architecture?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Think of it as a single-linked list rather than double-linked. Links point to previous versions.

Comment: Right, but couldn't you create a doubly-linked list from a single-linked list by walking the list and adding links?  Are there no tools that do this?